# computer not starting at all after connecting sata drive

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, sata

I built a "new" computer using my old i5-4590K processor (socket 1150). The motherboard is Asus H81M-K, new board , with 4 sata ports (2xSATA6GB + 2xSATA3GB). I have assembled my own computers since year 2000, also I am not an expert.

All was working fine for 24 hrs with the following components:

- 2 corsair XMS3 DDR3 1600MHz 8Go RAM = 16 Go
- i5 4590K (not overclocked)
- asus nvidia 1050Ti 4GB
- coolermaster 450W PSU
- SSD Samsung EVO 840 512Go (on SATA-6GB port 1)
- DVD-Bluray player LG (on SATA-3GB port 1)

Then after turning off, unplugging power, I connected:

- HDD Western digital caviar blue 1TB on sata-6GB port2 - drive almost new.
- HDD Western digital caviar green 2TB on sata-3GB port2 - drive used for backup only.

Then:

- the computer didn't start, just the green led on the motherboard apppears. No fan, no noise.
- If I remove the two hard-drives, same thing.
- I tested another PSU: a new cougar 600W VTE600 PSU. Same problem. I tested the old PSU connecting green wire with ground and the PSU working fine too. So, it's not a PSU problem.
- I made a clear CMOS and removed/put the battery in place. The battery has 3.1V.
- I removed all components (graphic card, use only one RAM module, removed all drives), same thing.
- I put the motherboard outside of the case on an insulating material, only with CPU, cooler and RAM. I bridged the startup pin with a screwdriver, nothing start or move. Only the green light on the motherboard is on.
- I tested both hard drives with an external dock on my laptop and they work normal.

Any idea? dead motherboard upon connecting sata drives? how is it possible?

Comment: It's possible that a SATA port went bad and took out the motherboard.

Comment: I think something similar happened, one of the SATA port DOA?
I will try to get the warranty working with the retailer and let you know...

Comment: I think the CPU plus the GFX card alone would require a stronger power supply than 450W. The other thing is: Did you take precautions for electrostatic discharge? Maybe you disconnected some motherboard connector involuntarily (like the power switch)?

Answer (score 0):

Motherboard is dead. I made test with another new motherboard out of the case with CPU, cooler and RAM: the fans start but no POST...
Better to spend 400 bucks for an upgrade (MB, CPU, RAM) to 9th gen!

Comment: Maybe see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/84961/282833 before working "on the open heart" next time ;-) Also: You should "accept" your answer.